Why does perturbation theory work so well?
In perturbation theory, we introduce a small perturbation to the system. This perturbation is usually a small parameter that slightly modifies the Hamiltonian or the equations of motion.
We assume that the solution to the perturbed system can be expressed as a series expansion in terms of the small parameter. The first term in this series is the known solution of the unperturbed system, and the subsequent terms represent corrections due to the perturbation.
we solve for each term in the series iteratively, starting with the zeroth-order term (the unperturbed solution) and then finding the first-order correction, the second-order correction, and so on.
The crucial point is the assumption that the solution to the perturbed system can be expressed as a series expansion in terms of the small parameter.
We could have assumed so many things else. Why is it that this assumptions works so well and actually approximates well the perturbed solution ?

What else are you expecting us to assume? We tried this because it was useful in celestial mechanics and other branches of physics, and just plain hoped that it works in quantum theory, only to realise that it works even better in quantum theory than in classical. The mathematical justification is just not there; all of these things are asymptotic. There is some theory there, but it is not exactly proven.

Taylor expansion? I'm not an expert on this, but I'm under the impression that "almost everything" can be expanded in a Taylor series, if you are close enough to the point.

@Allure Sounds cool but it's far from true: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2125155/

I don't think the statement that "it works so well" is even borderline correct. It works well enough under some circumstances but we know that e.g. perturbation theory in QED is divergent. It doesn't matter because QED is not a self-consistent theory, but it's a good example why one shall not give in to the idea that everything can be understood perturbatively. Even in classical mechanics almost nothing can and it just gets worse in quantum mechanics.

@FlatterMann that's why it is "almost everything" -- there are functions where Taylor expansion does not work, but they are few and far between.

@Allure You are greatly underestimating the size of the set of infinitely often differentiable functions. It is much, much, much, much larger than the set of natural numbers. A Taylor expansion gives you only a countable infinite number of coefficients and that means that actually most functions can not possibly be Taylor expanded. I am not a mathematician and I can not elaborate on this. That's why I was pointing to the math stackexchange. They can tell you over there what really happens. The upshot for physicists is that the path integral taps into the unpleasant  subset of functions.

As a theorist by training, it is really silly hearing people who do not understand the actual state of affairs arguing about this. It is not just perturbation in QED that is divergent. It is that all perturbation as used in physics are so. The perturbation theory in QM is also divergent, and the perturbation theory in classical mechanics is chaotic. It just so happens that all the basic functions we want to play with in classical mathematics are trivially extend-able to complex, and thus inherit the analyticity. Those functions then have the nice Taylor behaviour.

@FlatterMann Physics is a science, which means it follows the scientific method. In other words, the question is whether the predictions made with perturbation theory agree with experimental observations. In the case of QED (and other theories based on QFT), the answer is in general a resounding yes, which justifies the OP statement that "it works so well."

@naturallyInconsistent The chaos in classical mechanics has nothing to do with perturbation theory to begin with. It is a consequence of the fact that we are mostly interested in bound systems. A bound system is necessarily almost periodical, i.e. it revisits the almost same point in phase space over and over, again. As it does that the Lyapunov coefficient is almost always positive somewhere and the trajectory will almost always diverge exponentially somewhere. Non-bound, non-periodic systems have none of that silliness. A hyperbolic trajectory is nice and stable. It's also boring.

@flippiefanus I completely agree. It's totally irrelevant that perturbation theory in QED diverges after the 137th order (or whatever). That wasn't the question, though. The question was why it works so well. The mathematician's answer is that it doesn't work well, at all. It doesn't work on rather obvious physics like phase transitions, either, or you and naturallyconsistent would have calculated the three dimensional Ising model long ago and you would now be the owners of a physics Nobel. We don't have to go to QFT and quantum gravity to realize that PT doesn't do us all that much good.

@FlatterMann Phase transitions are non-perturbative effects. Nobody is suggesting that one tries to study them with perturbation theory.

@flippiefanus Exactly. Most "interesting" physics is not. That's why I said that it generally does not work all that well. It's a tool with limited application. It has some spectacular successes like the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron and then there are rather simply systems where it can't do a thing for us.

@FlatterMann: "It's a tool with limited application." Not true. Take a look at the particle data book to see how many experiments have been done to compare with results obtained from perturbative calculations, with excellent agreement!

@flippiefanus I can measure the mass of a proton in a test tube and we do it in chemistry class all the time (I also need a Millikan experiment for the electron charge, of course). Can you show me how you can derive it with perturbation theory from first principles?

Perturbation theory is based on the notion of an asymptotic series. It differs to some extent from the idea of a Taylor series, which is an infinite sum of terms converging to the function it represents within a certain region. The expansion parameter of a Taylor series therefore need not be small.
An asymptotic series on the other hand is truncated to have a finite number of terms. Provided that the expansion parameter is small enough, one can truncate a Taylor series to get the asymptotic series. Terms that are excluded are then sufficiently suppressed to give negligible contributions.
This property also explains why perturbation theory works so well. If the subsequent terms are small enough then the terms that are retained in the series would be accurate enough.
Those issues that are raised in the comments about all the weird functions that exists are issues that may interest mathematicians, but they are not generally relevant in physics, because they do not describe things in the physical world. For example, it is often argued that such weird functions must also be elements in the sets over which path integrals are integrated. That is not true. The path integral, as used in physics, is purely based on an assumed solution for an integrant in Gaussian form. The question is then what would be the set of functions for which the functional integral would produce such a solution for a Gaussian integrant? It turns out that one can safely discard all such weird functions and still get the required solution.

In response to some comments, let me add some discussion about the divergence/convergence of asymptotic series. It is true that there are asymptotic series that have divergent tails. In other words, at some point beyond where one would normally truncate the series the terms can start to grow larger with the result that the series as a whole does not converge.
First, obvious not all asymptotic series are divergent in this way. A simple example is a Taylor series with a small expansion parameter within its convergence region. It can be used as an asymptotic series and it does not have a divergent tail.
The important question is, what about the asymptotic series in perturbation theory. In this case, we can use the scientific method. If the asymptotic series that we are using to compute a measurable quantity is one of those that diverge, then the experimental result won't agree with the computed result. So the fact that there is agreement between the computation and the measured result indicates that the series did not diverge.
It actually runs deeper than that. All divergences must cancel when one calculates a measurable quantity. If that does not happen, then the theory is useless. The fact that we can compute results that agree with the quantities we measure indicates that the asymptotic series is convergent. Even if there are terms at large orders that become very large, they must cancel among themselves to give negligible contributions. How this happens is very difficult to determine without actually calculating such higher order terms, which is simply not practically feasible.
In the end, the whole issue about the apparent divergences in asymptotic series in perturbation theory far beyond the truncation point is not a problem in physics. The calculation procedure works. Therefore, it is a problem in pure mathematics. Mathematician are trying to understand why it works.

The well know mathematical counterexamples for functions that don't have convergent Taylor series are not all that "weird" and they aren't rare, either. Most (more generally almost all) functions don't have a convergent Taylor series. These functions are actually highly relevant as long as we are doing quantum field theory with Feynman's path integral, which is one of the ugliest constructions in all of science. The problem is that nobody seems to have come up with a better way to do some calculations in quantum field theory. That's probably just a matter of time, though.

"If the subsequent terms are small enough then the terms that are retained in the series would be accurate enough" But if you even know about asymptotic series, you would also know that the subsequent terms are exploding to infinity. The convergence radius is zero and the mathematical meaning of all these series are tenuous. We all agree that physics are incredibly well-described by those truncated asymptotic series, and we even have prescriptions for dealing with the divergent tails, but we do not really know how to prove that things work. They just do.

@FlatterMann Functions that are relevant in physics have a finite region within which their Taylor series around a point in that region converges. Those pathological cases of functions that do not have convergent Taylor series anywhere are not relevant for physics. If you disagree, then please provide an example of such a function. What is so ugly about Feynman path integrals?

@flippiefanus If we are performing an infinite number of integrations over positions or momenta from minus infinity to plus infinity, then we are necessarily picking up some mighty unpleasant functions. I do agree that that's not a good idea, but that is what the naive path integral does. That is why I am saying that we just don't have the right idea, yet, on how to define quantum field theories correctly. Nature does, by the way, not calculate path integrals. They are ensemble propagators and nature does not have ensembles.

@FlatterMann The scientific methods shows that the path integral approach provides a successful method to perform calculations with the aid of perturbation theory. The issue about how to define the path integral mathematically is a pure mathematics issue and not an issue in physics. Path integrals compute superpositions, not ensembles. Nature works with superpositions.

@flippiefanus Yes, it works... for certain problems. It does, as I said, not work for the Ising spin problem and it doesn't seem to work for QCD, either. The range of application is limited. It is also extremely inefficient, even when it works. Superpositions only exist for ensembles. They don't exist for actual physical outcomes and nature only offers us actual physical outcomes. It never allows us to measure superpositions (which are base dependent, anyway).
